# Suspicious IO behavior: System.out does not flush

Tags: java, io

I am working on a GA which used to work fine up until last week. In my efforts of optimizing the code I somehow broke the output sequence where the program dumps information about each generation of individuals. In all my debug efforts I came to understand that it's probably a flushing problem, but I can't really put my finger on the crux. ***The odd thing is that I actually did not touch any part of the IO since the last working version of the code.***

The GA is part of a much larger software where there is a progress console which is essentially a way to "mirror" `System.out` and `System.err` to the GUI. From my debugging efforts I realized that the buffer does not flush even if I specifically call `ps.flush()`.

What could be the reason of this problem??

---

**Edit:** To answer the questions in the comments, as well as further information on the problem:

- The rest of the software does it's output to the GUI and Eclipse console as normal, it's only the calls to the `outputGenInfo()` method (see below) that have disappeared
- If I add a notification line such as `System.out.println("Fitness calculation is complete!");` in my `evaluateGeneration()` method which is called just before the `outputGenInfo()` the information for each generation gets printed exactly as expected... [That particular line was one of things I had trimmed during my optimization efforts]
- For mirroring/redirecting `System.out` I used the `MessageConsole` class written by Rob Camick which can be found [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/)

---

The suspicious code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Convenience method for getting debug/info 
 * on this generation
 * @param ps - a <code>PrintStream</code> to output to
 * */
public void outputGenInfo(PrintStream ps){ // <-- ps = System.out by default

    double stdev_fitness = stats.getStandardDeviation();
    double mean_fitness = stats.getMean();
    double cv = stdev_fitness / mean_fitness;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String new_line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    sb.append(new_line);
    sb.append("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    sb.append(new_line);

    sb.append("Generation: " + this.id);
    sb.append(new_line);

    sb.append("-------------------------------");
    sb.append(new_line);

    sb.append("Mean fitness: " +  
                String.format("%.3f",mean_fitness) + 
                ", CV: " + String.format("%.3f",cv));
    sb.append(new_line);

    sb.append("Top fitness: " + getTopIndividual().getEntropy());
    sb.append(new_line);

    sb.append("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    sb.append(new_line);

    ps.println(sb.toString());

    // during debug this actually helps but not when the code is running full throttle!
    System.out.println("");  

}
```

Comment: I mean, when my buffer does not flush, either in Java or .Net, I start pulling my hair, sorry for my off-topic comment.

Comment: Is the thing you want is redirect the console output to the GUI?

Comment: What logging libraries is your application using? Is it running in an application server?

Comment: @LordCover no worries, I was just wondering if you were hinting at something..

Comment: Back out your changes and get the application working again.  When the application is working, trace the execution through the output sequence.  Once you understand the output sequence, carefully put your changes back in, one change at a time, to keep from breaking the output sequence.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati No, the mirroring works fine. What I want is to understand why the output has just disappeared.

Comment: @noahz no logging library is used at this stage (shocker, I know)

Comment: @posdef What about making a static GUI class and appending the output to it directly instead of redirecting?

Comment: If your code didn't change maybe System.out changed. I'd watchout for calls on System.setOut().