# Old fashioned TextFile I/O does not flush

Tags: file, delphi, file-io, delphi-xe2

As a follow-up to [TStreamWriter (Auto)Flush does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953302/tstreamwriter-autoflush-does-not) I tried to do quick-and-dirty old-fashioned text I/O:

```
procedure TFrmFlushTest.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lName: String;
  i: integer;
  s: string;
  lTextFile: TextFile;
begin
  lName := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.log');
  AssignFile(lTextFile,lName);
  ReWrite(lTextFile);
  for i := 1 to 100 do
  begin
     s := 'Let''s make this a real long string ' + IntToStr(i) + ' - ';
     s := DupeString(s,200);
     WriteLn(lTextFile,s);
     Flush(lTextFile);
  end;
  ShowMessage('Now closing');
  CloseFile(lTextFile);
end;
```

The file remains 0 bytes until the `Closefile()`, despite the `Flush()`.

What's the reason, how to fix?

I tried playing with the Windows [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but got stuck there determining the file handle to use as parameter.

Maybe related: [Suspicious IO behavior: System.out does not flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691172/suspicious-io-behavior-system-out-does-not-flush) (no answer)

Delphi XE2, Windows-7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Chen has [an excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx) (most of his articles are) discussing this various issue.

Bottom line is, in NTFS, the file size (and other metadata) belongs to the *file data* itself rather than the directory entry.

The metadata is *replicated* to the directory entry under certain circumstances (such as when the file is closed) but that delayed replication may cause the information in the directory information to be stale to some degree. Note that it was *always* at least a little out of date since, the instance you get the file size, it will be out of date if someone's writing to it.

You can actually bypass the metadata in the directory entry by calling `GetFileSize()` which goes to the file for that information. Explorer does not do this, mainly because it has no real reason to distrust the filesystem and that distrust would result in a lot more I/O.

Far more detail, much more better written than I can achieve :-), can be found at the linked article above.

Comment: Read it, thanks. Yeah, I was afraid it was the file system, since even this old DOS style file I/O has the 'problem'. Oh well, back to OutputDebugString then ;-)